# VHDL/GHDL Binary 32-bit Write Overflow When High Bit Set

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I have a VHDL testbench where I would like to write 32-bit binary words to a file for testing.  Below is a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

When executed with GHDL (commands below) an overflow is generated at the indicated line.  If the line is commented out execution completes successfully and writes the file.  The overflow occurs anytime the high bit is set.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;
use std.env.stop;

entity u32_file_write is
end entity;

architecture rtl of u32_file_write is
    type intFileType is file of natural;
    file fh : intFileType;
begin
    run: process
        variable no_high_bit : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"7FFFFFFF";
        variable with_high_bit : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"FFFFFFFF";
    begin
        file_open(fh, "out.bin", write_mode);
        write(fh, to_integer(unsigned(no_high_bit)));
        write(fh, to_integer(unsigned(with_high_bit))); -- Overflow here.
        file_close(fh);
        stop;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

I run the following GHDL commands to run the VHDL code (save as `u32_file_write.vhd`):

```
ghdl -a -fexplicit --std=08 --ieee=synopsys u32_file_write.vhd
ghdl -e -fexplicit --std=08 --ieee=synopsys u32_file_write
ghdl -r -fexplicit --std=08 --ieee=synopsys u32_file_write
```

With the line commented out, the corrected results are written to the file:

```
% od -tx4 out.bin
0000000 7fffffff
```

If the line is uncommented, an overflow is generated:

```
ghdl:error: overflow detected
    from: ieee.numeric_std.to_integer at numeric_std-body.vhdl:3040
ghdl:error: simulation failed
```

As noted above, the write will work with any value in the first 31-bits.  The write will overflow with any value where the 32-bit is set.

The underlying problem is integer'high is 2^31-1.  See:

- [How to represent Integer greater than integer'high](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442822/how-to-represent-integer-greater-than-integerhigh)

The accepted answer here states to use an intermediate 'text' format a text processing language.  Another answer shows a solution for reading using 'pos but that doesn't help me write.

- [How can I read binary data in VHDL/modelsim whithout using special binary formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173652/how-can-i-read-binary-data-in-vhdl-modelsim-whithout-using-special-binary-format)

Is there a simple rework/workaround that will allow me to write all 32-bits of data to a binary file?

Comment: Why don't you simply write your data as plain `std_logic_vector`?

Comment: Removing the `to_integer()` conversion generates the following error during analysis `u32_file_write.vhd:21:14:error: cannot resolve overloading for subprogram call`.  I can `write()` a `std_logic_vector` to a text buffer and then `writeline()` the text buffer to a file, but the file only contains `0x30` and `0x31`.  ASCII for '0' and '1'.

Comment: The reason for supporting writing a binary format would be to allow the data to be examined by a separated tool programmatically understanding unsigned 32 bit (or larger) integer values.

Comment: @esorton: sorry, I should have given more information. You can use the VHDL2008 standard procedures to write `std_ulogic_vector`: `ieee.std_logic_1164.hwrite`, `ieee.std_logic_1164.owrite`, `ieee.std_logic_1164.write`. Note that they are also aliased in `ieee.std_logic_textio` with the same names. If you prefer writing `unsigned`, use the `ieee.numeric_std` equivalents. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your file type to character. Convert 8 bits at a time to character and write all four characters to the file,

With 8 bit writes you're responsible for getting the endian order correct.

You can do that with a write procedure tailored to write 32 bit unsigned values to the character file:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;
use std.env.stop;

entity u32_file_write is
end entity;

architecture foo of u32_file_write is
    -- type intFileType is file of natural;  
    type intFileType is file of character;  -- CHANGED type mark
    file fh : intFileType;
    procedure write (file cf: intFileType; val: unsigned (31 downto 0)) is
    begin
        write (cf, character'val(to_integer(val( 7 downto  0))));
        write (cf, character'val(to_integer(val(15 downto  8))));
        write (cf, character'val(to_integer(val(23 downto 16))));
        write (cf, character'val(to_integer(val(31 downto 24))));
    end procedure;
begin
    run: process
        variable no_high_bit : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"7FFFFFFF";
        variable with_high_bit : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"FFFFFFFF";

    begin
        file_open(fh, "out.bin", write_mode);
        -- write(fh, to_integer(unsigned(no_high_bit)));
        -- write(fh, to_integer(unsigned(with_high_bit))); -- Overflow here.
        write (fh, unsigned(no_high_bit));
        write (fh, unsigned(with_high_bit));
        file_close(fh);
        stop;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

> ```
> ghdl -a -fexplicit --std=08 --ieee=synopsys u32_file_write.vhdl
> ghdl -e -fexplicit --std=08 --ieee=synopsys u32_file_write
> ghdl -r -fexplicit --std=08 --ieee=synopsys u32_file_write
> ```

Note that the only command line argument besides the command (-a, -e, -r) required here is --std-08 because of `stop`. There are no Synopsys package dependencies nor a requirement for -fexplicit (which isn't depended on either).

> ```
> od -tx4 out.bin
> 0000000          7fffffff        ffffffff
> 0000010
> ```

A host's file system contains files that consist of an array of 8 bit characters. It's convention (format) that superimposes the idea of something bigger.

VHDL superimposes type on file transactions, unfortunately there's no way to declare a natural range value greater than 2 ** 31 -1, if your integers were bigger they wouldn't be portable.

The above method treats files as character files allowing superimposition of size of elements of the contents by conventions (here in the host system, if you want to read 32 bit unsigned you'd want to read 4 characters and assemble a 32 bit value in the correct endian order).

An unsigned_int here is a 32 bit unsigned value. Note that the ascending or descending order isn't required to match in a subprogram call because of implicit subtype conversion (formals and actuals elements are associated in left to right order here).

The author of the original post encountered a problem reported in a comment:

> The write() above generates an error during analysis:
>   u32_file_write.vhd:23:14:error: cannot resolve overloading for
>   subprogram call.
>
> The error repeats four times, once for each write().
>   I've not found a way to get GHDL to write raw bytes other than an
>   integer.

Line 23 in the comment appears to correspond to the 18th line above where character 14 is the parameter list of the first write procedure call `write[file IntFileType, character]` which suggests the declaration for type `IntFileType`'s type definition's type mark hasn't been changed to type `character`. The signature of the procedure calls would not match those of the implicitly declared write for file type `IntFileType`, also noting the line numbers don't match.

The code has been provided complete in this answer to allow copying in it's entirety from the question, which was done along with naming the design file with a .vhdl suffix and using the command lines above.

The version of ghdl used is a recent build (GHDL 0.36-dev (v0.35-259-g4b16ef4)) built with an AdaCore 2015 GPL gnat (GPL 2015 (20150428-49)) and tested with both the llvm backend code generator (clang+llvm-3.8.0) and mcode code generator both on MacOS (10.11.6, gnat-gpl-2015-x86_64-darwin-bin and clang+llvm-3.8.0-x86_64-apple-darwin, using Xcode 8.2.1).

(The endian order of the character writes from val in the new write procedure has been reversed to match the OP's `od -xt out.bin` result byte order )

Comment: The write() above generates an error during analysis: `u32_file_write.vhd:23:14:error: cannot resolve overloading for subprogram call`.  The error repeats four times, once for each write().  I've not found a way to get GHDL to write raw bytes other than an integer.

Comment: Thank you.  You were correct; I neglected to change the file type during my test.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't absolutely need the output to be binary you could use the VHDL2008 standard procedures to directly write your vectors, without conversion:

```
$ ghdl --version
GHDL 0.36-dev (v0.35-259-g4b16ef4c-dirty) [Dunoon edition]
 Compiled with GNAT Version: GPL 2017 (20170515-63)
 llvm code generator
Written by Tristan Gingold.

Copyright (C) 2003 - 2015 Tristan Gingold.
GHDL is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ cat u32_file_write.vhd
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;
use std.env.stop;

entity u32_file_write is
end entity;

architecture rtl of u32_file_write is
begin
    run: process
        variable no_high_bit : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"7FFFFFFF";
        variable with_high_bit : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"FFFFFFFF";
        variable l: line;
        file fh: text open write_mode is "out.txt";
    begin
        hwrite(l, no_high_bit);
        writeline(fh, l);
        hwrite(l, with_high_bit);
        writeline(fh, l);
        file_close(fh);
        stop;
    end process;
end architecture;
$ ghdl -a -fexplicit --std=08 u32_file_write.vhd
$ ghdl -e -fexplicit --std=08 u32_file_write
$ ghdl -r -fexplicit --std=08 u32_file_write
simulation stopped @0ms
$ cat out.txt
7FFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
```